# Trying to understand the Python enumerate function and "Key not found" error

Tags: python-3.x, keyerror, enumerate

I have been going over and over this code but I can't understand why I am getting a `Key not found 1` error.

The code below may not be enough, but basically, I am comparing grades in a list `excel_data_choice` with those pulled from a spreadsheet `video_grades`.  It should iterate through the list to determine that grade exists in the `video_grades` list and if not, then add it.

However, I keep getting the error. Here is my output log.  I am sure I am doing something wrong, but just can't see it.

**Output**

```
Video grades are: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
K is 0 and v is K
K is 1 and v is 1
Key not found 1
```

**Code**

```
excel_data_choice = ['K', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
        try:
            for k,v in enumerate(excel_data_choice):
                print(f'K is {k} and v is {v}')
                if row[v] == v and str(row[v]) not in video_grades:
                    print(f'row v = {row[v]}')
                    video_grades.append(str(v))
                    print(f'Video grades is now {video_grades}')
                elif row[v] == 'delete' and str(v) in video_grades:
                    video_grades.remove(str(v))
            acf_dict['video_grades'] = video_grades
        except KeyError as ke:
            print(f'Key not found {ke}')
```

Comment: What is `row`? It's nowhere defined, yet you index it with a key `v`.

Comment: Great and helpful question.  So, it is defined earlier`for (row,founded_evideo) in zip(excel_data,founded_edvieos_list):`.  Basically, I am getting data from an excel file and iterating through each row of the spreadsheet.

Comment: So `row` is an element of `excel_data`. That still means we don't know what the type of `row` (or `excel_data`) is, nor whether it has keys and what those are. It does seem likely that `excel_data` is something like a list of dicts, but that the individual dicts (at least some) don't contain a key `1`.

Comment: Gotcha.  I should probably get a print out of what those dicts are to better understand the format.  Thank you!